# Query fails when I use where

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have this code

```
$marker = 'werkz';
$sql = "SELECT name, marker FROM sidebar";
$q = $db->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
    echo'<option>' . $r[name] . '</option>';
    }
```

It works but when I add `WHERE marker = $maker`; the query fails.

What is the problem?

Comment: What datatype is `marker`--varchar? It needs to be encapsulated in quotes...

Comment: Fail as in, throws error or doesnt return results?

Comment: conisder using try-catch to catch PDO-mysql errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you are using **[`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)**, do it like this when passing parameter.

```
$marker = 'werkz';
$sql = "SELECT name, marker FROM sidebar WHERE marker = ?";
$q = $db->query($sql);
$q->bindParam(1, $maker);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
    echo'<option>' . $r[name] . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$market is a string. So you should put it between '

something like ... where marker='".$marker."'";

Comment: `-1` the user is already using PDO. you are making it vulnerable with SQL injection. don't concatenate the value but instead bind it as parameter.

Comment: I have no idea on what PDO is. He asked why the where does not work and I answered. Bu usually smart guys like you fail to see the question ..

Comment: your suggestion works thank you for that.
indeed security can be an issue i have to look at that.

Comment: If your marker is an outside your application string then the use of PDOs way should be the way to do it. I just answered to your question, and that is why it does not work.

Comment: As a side note, I find a reply like: Do it like this because this is the way not helpful, as it does not help to understand why it does not work.